# programmatically sign into amazon

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am looking for a way to sign into amazon.com via a post sent in the body of the header. I am new to python and still learning the specifics. When I do a http sniff of the login to amazon.com I get several headers which I input into my code using requests. I verified the names of each and that none of them change. I have it writing to a file which I can load as a webpage to verify, and it loads amazons homepage but it shows I am not signed in. When I change my email address or pw to make it incorrect it makes no difference and I still get code 200. I don't know what i'm doing wrong to sign in via post. I would greatly appreciate any help. my code is as follows:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

login_data = {
'email':'myemail',
'password':'mypasswd',
'appAction' : 'SIGNIN',
'appActionToken' : 'RjZHAvZ7X4o8bm0eM2vFJFj2BYqZMj3D',
'openid.pape.max_auth_age' : 'ape:MA==',
'openid.ns' : 'ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjA=',
'openid.ns.pape' : 'ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy9wYXBlLzEuMA==',
'prevRID' : 'ape:MVQ4MVBLWDVEMUI0QjA3WlkyMEE=', # changes
'pageId' : 'ape:dXNmbGV4',
'openid.identity' : 'ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=',
'openid.claimed_id' : 'ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=',
'openid.mode' : 'ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==',
'openid.assoc_handle' : 'ape:dXNmbGV4',
'openid.return_to' : 'ape:aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYW1hem9uLmNvbS9ncC95b3Vyc3RvcmUvaG9tZT9pZT1VVEY4JmFjdGlvbj1zaWduLW91dCZwYXRoPSUyRmdwJTJGeW91cnN0b3JlJTJGaG9tZSZyZWZfPW5hdl95b3VyYWNjb3VudF9zaWdub3V0JnNpZ25Jbj0xJnVzZVJlZGlyZWN0T25TdWNjZXNzPTE=',
'create' : '0',
'metadata1' : `'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'`
}
r = s.post('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin', login_data)
s.cookies
r = s.get('https://www.amazon.com')
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print 'cookie name ' + cookie.name
    print 'cookie value ' + cookie.value
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, logging into AWS in this manner probably isn't a good idea.  They change their web interface regularly, so URL's, etc. are likely to change.  You might want to seriously consider using the Python [boto library](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which is a Python interface into Amazons API.  We use boto for a number of automated tasks in our AWS environments.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to login to Amazon, then try using Python mechanize module. It is much more simpler and neater.

For reference check out the sample code

```
import mechanize 

browser = mechanize.Browser()  
browser.set_handle_robots(False)  
browser.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]  

sign_in = browser.open('https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html')  

browser.select_form(name="sign-in")  
browser["email"] = ''  #provide email
browser["password"] = '' #provide passowrd
logged_in = browser.submit()
```

===============================

 Edited: requests module

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data = {'email':'', 'password':''}
header={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = session.post('https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html', data,headers=header)
print response.content
```

Comment: This code worked, thank you very much. Do you happen to know a way to do the same thing in the requests module? I would prefer to keep working with requests. Any other input you can provide, I would greatly appreciate. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lagito good to hear that worked. And welcome to stack overflow. If you think the answer worked you can `accept` the answer. Also if it is good answer, you can vote up the answer. Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, the requests answer simply takes me right back to the blank login screen, as if no information is being sent via post. This was the same problem I was having while typing my code. I don't intend to use this code more than once, its simply a problem i'm trying to learn how to solve so I know for the future. But thank you all for your assistance.